# cloudbuild.yaml for javafx (jdk8u201) with other dependencies

Tags: java, javafx, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration

I'm setting up a GitRepo, with different modules of a project. It has some legacy code, some C/C++ for Ardino, and a JavaFX project with some dependencies and Kotlin files in it.
What I actually need is, to build that JavaFx project on pull requests, targeting the develop branch

I already have an empty `cloudbuild.yaml` in my repository root. What I want is a non-Docker continous integration, so on pull request, I need an artifact build, so the executable can be downloaded for the other project members. GitHub and Google Cloud are connected, only the config is needed.
What is also specific, that I want to build with jdk8u201 (because of the licensing)

The folder structure is something like that:

```
+- legacy
+- Arduino_codes
+- JavaFX_project
|  +- FILES...
+- cloudbuild.yaml
+- .git
```

If it is possible, that would be great if the builded version would be downloadable, or stored in a specific place in the repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `:3.5.0-jdk-8` to `gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn` if you use maven. Result `gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn:3.5.0-jdk-8`
It helped me. More info and cases you can find [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/runtime-builder-java).